# my loop for inserting data table is very slow-

Tags: php, mysql

this is the problem facing in codeigniter.

using database mariadb

i have 7 table called

1. terms
2. class
3. section
4. subject
5. exam_paper
   6 assign_subject
   7 mark
   and the query is

```php
  <?php
            $select  =   $this->db->get_where('terms', array())->result_array();

            foreach ($select as $key => $data_select) :
                $verify_data1 = array(
                    'session_year_id' => $session_year_id
                );
                $query1 = $this->db->get_where('class', $verify_data1);
                $select1 = $query1->result_array();

                foreach ($select1 as $key => $data_select1) :
                    $verify_data2 = array(
                        'class_id' => $data_select1['class_id'],
                        'session_year_id' => $session_year_id
                    );
                    $query2 = $this->db->get_where('section', $verify_data2);
                    $select2 = $query2->result_array();

                    foreach ($select2 as $key => $data_select2) :
                        $verify_data3 = array(
                            'class_id' => $data_select1['class_id'],
                            'section_id' => $data_select2['section_id'],
                            'session_year_id' => $session_year_id
                        );
                        $query3 = $this->db->get_where('subject', $verify_data3);
                        $select3 = $query3->result_array();

                        foreach ($select3 as $key => $data_select3) :
                            $verify_data4 = array(
                                'terms_id' => $data_select['terms_id'],
                                'class_id' => $data_select1['class_id'],
                                'section_id' => $data_select2['section_id'],
                                'subject_id' => $data_select3['subject_id'],
                                'session_year_id' => $session_year_id

                            );
                            $query4 = $this->db->get_where('exam_paper', $verify_data4);
                            $select4 = $query4->result_array();

                            foreach ($select4 as $key => $data_select4) :
                                $verify_data5 = array(
                                    'class_id' => $data_select1['class_id'],
                                    'section_id' => $data_select2['section_id'],
                                    'session_year_id' => $session_year_id

                                );
                                $query5 = $this->db->get_where('assign_subject', $verify_data5);
                                $select5 = $query5->result_array();

                                foreach ($select5 as $key => $data_select5) :
                                    $verify_data6 = array(
                                        'terms_id' => $data_select['terms_id'],
                                        'class_id' => $data_select1['class_id'],
                                        'section_id' => $data_select2['section_id'],
                                        'subject_id' => $data_select3['subject_id'],
                                        'exam_paper_id' => $data_select4['exam_paper_id'],
                                        'student_id' => $data_select5['student_id'],
                                        'status ' => 1,
                                        'session_year_id' => $session_year_id

                                    );
                                    $query = $this->db->get_where('mark', $verify_data6);
                                    $select6 = $query->result_array();

                                    $sql = "select * from mark order by mark_id desc limit 1";
                                    $return_query = $this->db->query($sql)->row()->mark_id + 1;
                                    $verify_data6['mark_id'] = $return_query;

                                    if ($query->num_rows() < 1)
                                        $this->db->insert('mark', $verify_data6);

                                endforeach;
                            endforeach;
                        endforeach;
                    endforeach;
                endforeach;
            endforeach; ?>
```

the problem is that it is takes more than 3 hour to insert and after inserting it makes page very slow.

Comment: (Can you simplify the example code.)  If the only question is in the SQL, then show just the generated SQL.  If the question is in the 6(!) levels of looping, at least tell us the purpose of each level.

Answer (score 1):

- To avoid the `SELECT` before each `INSERT`, use `INSERT IGNORE ... or` INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`
- To speed up any insert (by up to 10-fold), "batch" it.  That is insert, say, 100 rows in a single query.
- If the data is coming from other tables, then use `INSERT...SELECT...;` so you can do it all at once.

Answer (score 0):

you can use multi value in insert query to make insert faster and for better speed in loading data from database you should use feature called index .